# Proper way to convert results from the Skip LINQ method

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq, html-agility-pack

I need to properly convert the collection that the `Skip` method returns me, to the right type:

```
Dim htmlnodes_Albums As HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNodeCollection = Nothing

htmlnodes_Albums =
    htmldoc_RawSource.DocumentNode.
    SelectNodes("//h1[@class='pageheader']").
    Skip(1).
    Cast(Of HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode)()
```

The problem is that the code above throws a casting exception, I have also tried with `CType`.

I could undefine the type of the `htmlnodes_Albums` or write a long LINQ method to convert the type, but I won't. I would like to know a proper (and short) way to do the conversion.

Comment: Where are you getting the exception at?  On the `Cast` line or assignment to `htmlnodes_Albums`

Comment: @JaredPar on the cast line

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The LINQ methods typically return an `IEnumerable` object, as is the case with the `Cast` method.  Try this:

```
Dim htmlnodes_Albums As IEnumerable(Of HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode) = Nothing

htmlnodes_Albums =
    htmldoc_RawSource.DocumentNode.
    SelectNodes("//h1[@class='pageheader']").
    Skip(1).
    Cast(Of HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode)()
```

Comment: Which seems to be the only solution, as HtmlNodeCollection doesn't have a constructor that accepts IEnumerable or an AddRange method

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Right.  I Just looked that up too.  Apparently, if you need it as an `HtmlNodeCollection`, you'd have to call the `Add` method separately for each node.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, solved and waiting to be able to mark it as accepted, just one thing that I will clarify, using your solution there is no need to cast after skipping, it works fine without casting, thanks again

Comment: Right, there is no reason to convert it to any other type unless you need to for some other reason.  If all you need to do is iterate through the results, the `IEnumerable` interface should fit your needs perfectly.